# Prevent interpretration of a string as a regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm passing a string to a function and that string is *not* a regexp.  Inside that function, I'm calling another function which takes a regexp.

The problem I'm having is that I'm passing, say:

```
"i.."
```

which does *not* represent a regexp and I'd then like to "convert" it to a regexp that shall match that exact string.

For example, I take it converting my non-regexp *"i.."* to:

```
"i[.][.]"
```

would work in my case because then that regexp would match "i..".

I'm looking for something that would work with most characters but it's not a big deal if I cannot use '[' and ']' in my input string.

So how can I programmatically "wrap" my non-regexp string into a regexp automatically so that that regexp matches my exact (non-regexp) string?

Comment: You're looking to escape regex characters into their literal values. Not familiar enough with emacs. What is the underlying technology?

Comment: @Jason McCreary: Emacs is mostly programmed in elisp AFAICT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are looking for the `regexp-quote` function.

Comment: @jthalborn: now that was quick : )   +1 and accepted answer, this is exactly what I was after (I did Google and ask on IRC first... But didn't find it so thanks a lot : )